# Mips Assembly Language using bit manipulation to check if int is less than 32 & displays 0 if so, otherwise (32 or higher) displays 1

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips

Checks if a user-entered int between 0 & 255 (inclusive) is less than 32
  & displays 0 if so, otherwise (32 or higher) displays 1.

I can't figure out how to make 64 and 128 not show up as 0.

```
.data
legend1:    .asciiz "0: less than 32\n"
legend2:    .asciiz "1: 32 or higher\n"
inPrompt:   .asciiz "Enter an integer between 0 and 255: "
outLab:     .asciiz "It is "

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, legend1        
    syscall                   # print legend line 1
    la $a0, legend2        
    syscall                   # print legend line 2
    la $a0, inPrompt        
    syscall                   # print input prompt

    li $v0, 5
    syscall                   # read input integer

    move $t0, $v0       #stores input integer into $t0 and prints outLab
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, outLab
    syscall

    andi $t3, $t0, 0x031    #and'ing the input integer and masking number
    li $v0, 1       #code to print integer
    move $a0, $t4       #move t3 value into argument
    syscall
```

Write NO MORE THAN 14 lines of code that involve using 
ONLY the following:
- syscall

- syscall supporting instructions (e.g.: li to load $v0)
- instruction to make a saved copy
- bit manipulating instructions (ANDing, ORing, XORing,
  NORing and shifting - only whatever that are needed)

  ```
          li $v0, 10               # exit
          syscall
  ```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to *even* attempt to solve the problem. The algorithm to solve this problem is very simple - have you understood what tell numbers greater than 31 and numbers less equal than 31 apart?  Hint: look at the high order bits for both classes of numbers.

Comment: The result of `andi $t3, $t0, 0x031` doesn't look good for anything. `andi $t3, $t0, 31` (or in hexa: `andi $t3, $t0, 0x1F`) can be used for example to say, if the value is divisible by `32` (for values `0, 32, 64, 96, 128, ...` the result of such `and` is zero, for other values it's non zero `1-31` value. Why `64` does produce zero?  because `64 = 0100 0000` and mask `0x1F` is `0001 1111`, so anding those two results in zero) If you consider the values of particular bits, it should be clear, which bits to retain if you want all bits higher/equal to value `32`.

Comment: And to convert 0-255 values to 0-7 by 32 boundaries (0-31 => 0, 32-63 => 1, ... 224-255 => 7) needs single instruction, but then converting values 1-7 to `1` may be a bit more tricky, especially without `sub/add` or branching it may take some compositing of temporary values to get to it.

Comment: He is allowed to use pseudoinstruction like `move` instead of `add`.

Comment: @XERO yeah, which is not needed at all either. :) Actually `xor` can fully replace `mov reg,reg` (with particular performance penalty, as you would get 2x `xor` per 1x`mov`, and 3x`xor` per 1x "exchange"), even without immediate values. `and/or` with immediate values can do anything? But with regs-only they are limited by input values (although they can together replace `mov reg,reg` too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    # prepare the three significant bits b5-b7 to lowest bit position
    srl   $t0, $v0, 5    # t0.b0 = v0.b5 (div 32)
    srl   $t1, $v0, 6    # t1.b0 = v0.b6 (div 64)
    srl   $a0, $v0, 7    # a0.b0 = v0.b7 (div 128)
    # compose all three significant bits into single a0.b0 bit:
    or    $a0, $a0, $t0
    or    $a0, $a0, $t1  # a0.b0 = (b5 | b6 | b7)
    andi  $a0, $a0, 0x1  # mask out only the resulting b0 (0/1 result)
    # here a0 = 0/1 for v0 = 0..31/32..255
```

Comment: This works, but i left in 3 or maskings that were just for testing (e.g. those with $0)

Answer (score 0):

You need an `if statement` in order to making decision if the value entered by user is less or bigger than 31.
Your code has too many bugs so i wrote a simple code here that you can use in your code, or add some `print string` to that.

```
.text
main:
li       $v0,5          #read user input
syscall
move     $t0,$v0        #t0 = user input

addi     $t1,$zero,32   #t1 = 32

bgt      $t0,$t1,L1     # branch to L1 if t0 > t1
nop
addi     $v0,$0,0       # v0 = 0
b        endif
L1:
addi     $v0,$0,1       # v0 = 1

endif:
move     $a0,$v0        # a0 = 1 or 0 depend on the v0 

li       $v0,1          # print it out
syscall         

li       $v0,10         #exit
syscall
```

Comment: he can't use `if` and it's not *"needed"*. You can calculate resulting `0/1` from the `0/255` input value without branching.